# make and the mkdir command behaving differently on MacOX vs Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, make, mkdir

I have discovered something odd with the mkdir command when it is being used in a Makefile and it behaving differently between OSX and Ubuntu 20.04.

Just wondering if this is expected behaviour, or have I discovered a bug?

The suspect command is:

`mkdir -p -m 0755 ./output/themes/simple/{css,javascript,webfonts,image}`

This command works perfectly at the bash/zsh command line, creating the directories:

`output/themes/simple/css`
`output/themes/simple/javascript`
etc.

On a OSX machine using the zsh shell. When running the above command in a Makefile it works as expected creating the separate subdirectories.

However, using the *same* Makefile on a Ubuntu 20.04 desktop (the file is on a server and both machines can see it) the command is creating the following:

`output/themes/simple/{css,javascript,webfonts,images}`

It is as if the command is seeing the last component of the directory path as a string and not enumerating it as it does on the command line.

Make on Linux is:

> GNU Make 4.2.1
> Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Make on OSX is:

> GNU Make 3.81
> Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
> There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
> PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

I do not think it is difference between shells, mkdir is not a builtin on the bash Ubuntu provides.

Work around is to separate the mkdirs into separate commands, but I was quite surprised that the make/mkdir did not work correctly on the Linux box.

Any thoughts?

Cheers
Jim

Comment: "I do not think it is difference between shells, mkdir is not a builtin" `mkdir`, isn't, but brace expansion is.

Comment: What you have described is shell (zsh/bash) expansion not makefile behaviour..

By default Makefile using the shell indicated by the SHELL environment variable.

Comment: Excellent. That makes sense. So I guess the difference in behaviour between OS is to do with the way their versions of make hand off the command to the shell/the shell taking in the command and seeing the braces as an expansion opportunity. Anyways proves I am not going crazy :)  Thanks for your efforts.